# Where to edit category blog layout for alternative menu item

Tags: layout, category

I've made my own version of blog.php, blog_item.php and blog.xml for my own category blog menu item.

And I've changed a few things so far.

But I need to change it so that the intro image is above title, so it goes image > title > intro text. And optimally I want to put som control on intro-text dimensions.

I can't find where the intro image is called, and where title is shown, so I can switch their positions in the code.

Site is here: http://xn--herningidrtsrd-xibm.dk/elite/elite-idraetsgrene

Comment: You should probably show the top section of blog_item.php. Presumably it's in there, but we have no idea what's in your version of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for make your own version is making an **override**.

- First, here some docs for make the override step by step: 
  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager

Now you need create an override in the column:
**Components** > **com_content** > **category**

- You can find the files in:

`yoursite/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php`

- From here you can change the order for the block that contains

`'joomla.content.intro_image'`

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The two lines of code you're looking for are in the blog_item.php file at line numbers 27 and 45 in the core component, no idea what lines they will be in your override file:

```
27: <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_title', $this->item); ?>

45: <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

If you end up wanting to change the actual code, those files are in the "layouts" directory, and swapping the dots for directory separators will take you to the file. You can override those in your template by putting the override file in your /html directory in your template, duplicating the directory structure, e. g., html/layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php will override the intro image layout code.